# How to multiply individual element in a string in Python?

Tags: python, string, duplicates, element

If I were to run duplicateString(aString,value) such as ("hello",3) it should return "hhheeellllllooo". This is what I have but all it does is return the entire word three times. I'm not sure how to tell it to multiply each element instead of the entire string. Could anyone help me out?

```
    def duplicateString(aString,value):
        return (aString)*(value)
```

So this is what it does if I use hello and 3...

```
    duplicateString("hello",3):
    "hellohellohello"
```

Comment: You need to loop over the characters of the original string, and concatate `char*3` to a result.

Answer (score 2):

You are duplicating the entire string with your code. Instead you need to iterate over individual characters of the string and duplicate them. This is one way to do it:

```
def duplicateString(astring, value):
    return "".join(ch * value for ch in astring)
```

`[ch * value for ch in astring]` for `hello` and `3` gives `['hhh', 'eee', 'lll', 'lll', 'ooo']`. Getting rid of the `[` and `]` to avoid creating an intermediate list as suggested by Steven in the comments.

[`join`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.join) makes the required string out of it.

Comment: This will be much faster than the naive `for +=` approach

Comment: You can remove the brackets (`[]`) to avoid creating the intermediate list.

Answer (score 1):

You simply need

```
def duplicateString(aString,value):
    newString = ""
    for char in aString:
        newString += char * value
    return newString
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this , may be it help you .....

newstring=''
    for letter in aString:
        for i in range(value):
            newstring+=letter
    return(newstring)

should do the trick...

Comment: This is a horribly inefficient algorithm. Every time you add a letter it creates a new string, first copying all the existing letters into a new string.